# Get the first set of digits from a text

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a textbox with this text :

```
(1902,12 ABS) ASD KASJDGASJ KASDGJAKSJDG
```

And I want to convert it to only show the first number:

```
1902
```

How can I do that in vb.net? The closest solution I have found looks like this:

```
Dim match = Regex.Replace("(1902,12 ABS) ASD KASJDGASJ KASDGJAKSJDG", "\D", "")
    Label1.Text = match
```

But it gives me 190212 as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the first number in any string you pass in:

```
Dim match = Regex.Replace("This is an example input string blah blah(1902,12 ABS) ASD KASJD SJG blah", "\D*(\d+).*", "$1")
Label1.Text = match
```

Microsoft Docs Reference: [Regex.Replace Method (String, String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim match = Regex.Match("(1902,12 ABS) ASD KASJDGASJ KASDGJAKSJDG", "\d+").Value
```